# Strings sorting with matrices

Tags: c, string.h

I am participating to a tournament and I have a problem with strings sorting. Here I try to explain the situation:

> "A man discovered a big book written in an unknown language that used the same characters as the English language. The book contained a short index, but the ordering of the items in the index was different from what one would expect if the characters were ordered the same way as in the English alphabet. The collector tried to use the index to determine the ordering of characters (i.e., the collating sequence) of the strange alphabet, then he started this work"

I must make a program that helps that man of course. As input, I must ask to the user the sequence of letters (I've already solved this problem). Each string contains at most 20 characters. Not all letters are necessarily used, but the list will imply a complete ordering among those letters that are used.

I wrote this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(void){
int i,c,j,p=0,k=0;    
printf("How many strings do you need? \n");  
scanf("%d", &c);                   //number of columns for the matrix
// input
char a[20][c];
for(i=0;i<c;i++){
printf(" ----- String number %d -----\n",i+1);
for(j=0;j<20;j++){
             scanf("%c", &a[j][c]);
             if (a[j][c]==' ')
             {break;}              
  }
 } 
  //output
 printf(" \n");
 printf(" ----- Results ----- \n");
 printf("%c", a[0][0]);
 for(p=1;p<c;p++)
 {
  if(a[k][p]=!a[k][p-1])
 {printf("%c", a[k][p]);}  
  }
 getch();
  return 0;
}
```

I have a problem in the last loop because it doesn't give to me a correct output. If the user types (for example):

> XWY
>   ZX
>   ZXY
>   ZXW
>   YWWX

my output should be "XZYW". Does anyone have some suggestions?

Comment: please fix indentation

Comment: Is asking for help allowed according to the rules of the tournament you are participating in?

Comment: It is just a tournament inside my school, I can ask for an help because this problem is not very easy

Comment: I suspect a problem with the processing part of the input.